# Robot Framework: Unable to set screeshot directory and view custom screenshot in the log file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to run the below code to save the screenshot of all the failed test cases in the Test Suite to a custom folder and to view the screenshots in the log file. The below code doesn't run as expected .Please help in completing the code.

```
'*** Setting ***
Suite Setup    register    
Test Setup    Set Screenshot Directory    D:/path/  
Library        Selenium2Library


*** Keywords ***
sc    
    Capture page screenshot    D:/path/

register
    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    sc

*** Test Cases ***
Run TestCase1
    Open Browser    http://google.com    chrome

    Click Element    css=getsomthing


Run TestCase2
    Open Browser    http://google.com    chrome

    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure  Click Element    css=getsomthingother   '
```

When executing I get the following error
 [ WARN ] Keyword 'sc' could not be run on failure: Failed to save screenshot file:///D:/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be giving `capture page screenshot` the name of a folder when it expects the name of a file. It probably fails because it can't create a screenshot file with the name of an existing directory.

Since you already set the screenshot directory to `D:/path`, there's no need to give a filename to `capture page screenshot`.

Comment: I removed the name of the folder from the keyword 'capture page screenshot' , and when executing I get another error - [ WARN ] Keyword 'sc' could not be run on failure: No browser is open

Comment: @Dani: that's a different problem. As the error states, the keyword is failing because no browser is open.

Comment: Can you help in completing this script

Comment: @Dani: I don't know what type of help you need. When I make the changes suggested in my answer, the test in your question works for me. By that I mean that it takes the screenshots and does not throw the "no browser open" error.

Comment: @Dani: I tried the exact code in your question, modified according to my answer.

Comment: I used Capture page screenshot    filename=selenium-screenshot-{index}.png and Set Screenshot Directory    D:/path             and it started working. Thanks Bryan.... you are great